# How to delete a huge org-table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I forgot to type `:results none` in babel and now I have a huge table in my org file. How can I select all of those lines and delete them? When I try the straight forward approach of moving to the end of the buffer, Emacs freezes up and I get a "Timed out waiting for property viewers" message in the minibuffer.

Comment: Would `C-M-s ^$` work?

Comment: Can you switch to a different mode to delete the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `org-narrow-to-element` might help:

1. In the `#+RESULT` line call `C-x n e` to narrow to the result.
2. Do something like

   `M-:` `(delete-region (point-min) (point-max))` `RET`

   to clear everything in the narrowed file.
3. Do `C-x n w` to widen back to the whole file.